# Java jdk, compiler, runtime targets. Questions for targeting specific runtime and what jdk/sdk i can use

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-construction, settings, version

I have strict compile and runtime versions that I can use, and I'm having trouble mapping this to the netbeans "Source/Binary Format" option for project properties. I'd like to develop with jdk7 as there are code features and support that are really nice (String switch case is a perfect example) However the environment for the project at runtime requires it be compiled with version 1.4.1 or higher, and runtime version 1.6.0_02(can't be higher than that)

Given that information, I believe so long as netbeans is using jdk7 on environment level then I can set my source/binary setting on the project level to be jdk 1.4 and be just fine.

Is this a correct assumption, or am I missing a basic concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project must be compiled with version 1.4.1 you have to set the Source/Binary format to 1.4.1. What's more if your runtime plateform support only jdk1.6 how do you think it's possible to use 1.7 features?

Comment: My question is whats the tie between 1.6 and jdk 6 are they the same? is 1.7 jdk 7? If so does that mean i have to use jdk 4 for 1.4.1? Also I was under the impression that you could compile with different source then your target runtime within certain backwards compatibility. Such as 1.6(aka jdk,sdk 6?) targeting the jre to a backwards compatible level of 1.4? Does any of that make sense? Obviously I'm missing a fundamental relationship between the two, but I can't find a direct answer to what the relationship should be. It seems to be implied knowledge that I should remember from college.

Comment: Yes jdk 6 refer to 1.6 etc. Maybe you can set the source in netbeans to 1.6 and run in 1.4  but it don't really make sense, you will use things that will not be compatible.